# Boost MP11: Get type list from container of type indices

Tags: c++, boost, c++20

I know that with a combination of `mp_with_index` and `mp_at_c`, we can convert a single index into a type `T`:

```
using List = mp_list<Foo, Bar, Baz>;
std::size_t typeIndex = 2;

boost::mp11::mp_with_index<boost::mp11::mp_size<List>>(
            typeIndex,
            [&](auto I) {
                // T is Baz
                using T = boost::mp11::mp_at_c<List, I>;
            });
```

I would like to go a step further and convert a container of type indices into a type list:

```
using List = mp_list<Foo, Bar, Baz>;
std::array<std::size_t, 3> arr{2, 1, 0};

// * Do something *

// T is MyType<Baz, Bar, Foo>
using T = * Something *
```

Is this possible? If not, how about ending up with something like `MyType<2, 1, 0>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform Cartesian product on `type_list` to get a nested `type_list`, and then convert the array index into a 1d index for `mp_with_index` to use to access the corresponding `type_list`

```
using List = mp_list<Foo, Bar, Baz>;
std::array<std::size_t, 3> arr{2, 1, 0};

using Cartesian = mp_product<mp_list, List, List, List>;
mp_with_index<mp_size<Cartesian>>(
  // This can be calculated with some helper function
  arr[0] * std::pow(arr.size(), 2) + 
  arr[1] * std::pow(arr.size(), 1) + 
  arr[2] * std::pow(arr.size(), 0),
  [](auto I) {
    // T is mp_list<Baz, Bar, Foo>
    using T = mp_at_c<Cartesian, I>;
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can first calculate the Cartesian 1-d index through the array index, and then reversely decompose it into different static indices to get the corresponding types by `mp_at_c`. This removes the heavy calculation of `mp_product`.

```
using List = mp_list<Foo, Bar, Baz>;
std::array<std::size_t, 3> arr{2, 1, 0};

constexpr auto w2 = 1;
constexpr auto w1 = w2 * arr.size();
constexpr auto w0 = w1 * arr.size();
mp_with_index<w0 * arr.size()>(
  arr[0] * w0 + arr[1] * w1 + arr[2] * w2,
  [](auto I) {
    constexpr auto I0 = (I / w0);
    constexpr auto I1 = (I - I0 * w0) / w1;
    constexpr auto I2 = (I - I0 * w0 - I1 * w1) / w2;
    // T is mp_list<Baz, Bar, Foo>
    using T = mp_list<mp_at_c<List, I0>, mp_at_c<List, I1>, mp_at_c<List, I2>>;
});
```

Comment: You could just reverse your power calculation to decompose `I` into three indices, and then do three `mp_at_c`s.

Comment: @Barry If I understand correctly, you mean that this eliminates the need to calculate `mp_product`, right?

Comment: Yep. Which is pretty computationally expensive in comparison.